# Python datetime converter

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to write a Python function to standardize incoming timestamps to `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm+/-tz offset`.

**Example:**

```py
def format_ts(ts):
                
    beg_format = [
        '%H:%M%a, %b %d, %Y %Z',
        '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z',
    ]

    end_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M %z'

    try:
        for f in beg_format:
            if datetime.strptime(ts, f):
                ts_fmt = datetime.strptime(ts, f)
                ts_fmt = ts_fmt.strftime(end_format)
                return ts_fmt

    except:
        pass


ts = [
    '08:27Sun, Dec 19, 2021 IST',
    'Sun, 19 Dec 2021 02:28:56 +0000'
]

for t in ts:
    formatted_ts = format_ts(t)
    print(formatted_ts)
```

**Issue:**

- IIRC, I shouldn't rely a failure (`pass`), but should rather catch the exception and handle
- The above function iterates all timestamps through all formats (slow)
- Unless I'm missing something, `IST` is not read by `%Z`
- For some reason, `'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'` is not for the correct format for `ts[1]`

**Question:** How are others handling this type of issue in Python?

Comment: You don't appear to be returning anything, and you're not handling the exception, so how do you know what's happening?

Comment: I have a bunch of `print()` statements I left out for brevity.

Comment: There is an actual `return` statement under the `try:`. I added the function call to be more complete. If you take off the `IST` from `ts[0]` and `%Z` from `beg_format[0]`, you'll see what I mean by the `IST` not being a valid(?) timezone.

Comment: You should give the `dateutil` module a try.  It has a parser that can crack almost any date/time format.  Not sure about your format that has the minutes and the date concatenated without a space, but it's worth checking.

Comment: I'll check out `dateutil`. See the [`<lastBuildDate>` (line 15) here](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms) for where that goofy time format comes from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timezone doesn't appear to be supported in the string representation for strptime.  You can use dateutil parser with a timezone to overcome this.

```
from dateutil import parser, tz

ts = [
    '08:27Sun, Dec 19, 2021 IST',
    'Sun, 19 Dec 2021 02:28:56 +0000'
]


def format_ts(ts):
    return [parser.parse(t, tzinfos={'IST':tz.gettz('Asia/Calcutta')}) for t in ts]

format_ts(ts)
```

Output

```
[datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 19, 8, 27, tzinfo=tzfile('Asia/Calcutta')),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 19, 2, 28, 56, tzinfo=tzutc())]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. There are 50+ timestamps that need to be processed using the minimal example shown in the OP. I'd rather not list all possible timezone strings if I can avoid. I thought that the purpose of `strptime()'s %Z` syntax?

Comment: Looks like `strptime()'s %Z` format code "Time zone name" should really be called "Pseudonyms for UTC". [The only allowed values are `UTC` and `GMT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). No other timezones (`PST`, `MST`, `CST`, `EST` etc.) allowed.